# Не реагирует на нажатие кнопки в дискорд

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Когда нажимаю кнопку с данным идом, кнопку не видет ивент, те как-будто я не нажимаю.
Что не так в коде?

````
async def on_button_click(inter):
    guild = bot.get_guild(inter.guild.id)
    if inter.component.id == "get_role":#айди кнопки, кастомный
        print("asd")```

```await ctx.send(embed = embed_r,components = [[Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label='---', emoji="-", custom_id = 'get_role')```
````

Comment: что за модуль?.

Comment: import discord
import asyncio
import time
import random 
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, CheckFailure
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, перед функцией ивента нет декоратора ивента, eсли ты работаешь в когах, то необходимо указать `@commands.Cog.listener()`, если без когов, то `@bot.event`. Во вторых, сли  используешь коги, то во всех функциях первый аргумент должен быть `self`. В третьих, функция `bot.get_guild(inter.guild.id)` асинхронная, перед ней должен стоять `await`. Так-же, необходимо использовать `custom_id`, вместо `interaction.id`. Код будет выглядеть так:

```
# cogs:

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_button_click(self, interaction):
        guild = await self.bot.get_guild(interaction.guild.id)
        if interaction.custom_id == "get_role": 
            print("asd")


# bot:

    @bot.event
    async def on_button_click(interaction):
        guild = await bot.get_guild(interaction.guild.id)
        if interaction.custom_id == "get_role": 
            print("asd")
```

Так-же, проверь, есть ли при инициализации бота строчка `intents=discord.Intents.all()`, должно выглядеть так:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='PREFIX', intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Ещё проверь, включены ли данные параметры на сайте дискорда:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]